# Cassandra java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text while getMetaData

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-cli, cassandra-2.1

I get an cassandra exception while geathering meta data.
Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text
at com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnMetadata$Raw$Kind.fromStringV3(ColumnMetadata.java:160)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnMetadata$Raw.fromRow(ColumnMetadata.java:188)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser.groupByKeyspaceAndCf(SchemaParser.java:442)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SchemaParser$2.refresh(SchemaParser.java:255)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.refreshSchema(ControlConnection.java:323)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:264)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:187)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:75)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1269)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:338)
at com.pentaquin.core.database.driver.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:70)
at com.pentaquin.core.database.driver.CassandraDriver.createFromConfig(CassandraDriver.java:136)
at com.pentaquin.login.server.LoginServerMain.main(LoginServerMain.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Code in CassandraDriver line 70:

```
this.metadata = this.cluster.getMetadata();
```

Code of CassandraDriver method:

```
/*
    * Cassandra Configuration
    */
    Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.builder();

    Logger.getRootLogger().info(configuration.listServerContactPoints().size() + " cassandra contact points registered.");

    //add all server contact points
    for (ServerContactPoint serverContactPoint : configuration.listServerContactPoints()) {
        String ip = serverContactPoint.getIp();
        int port = serverContactPoint.getPort();

        //add cassandra contact point
        builder.addContactPoint(ip).withPort(port);
    }

    //use credentials
    if (!configuration.getUser().equals("") && !configuration.getPassword().equals("")) {
        builder.withCredentials(configuration.getUser(), configuration.getPassword());
    }

    if (configuration.listServerContactPoints().size() > 1) {
        DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy dcAwareRoundRobinPolicy = DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel()/*.withLocalDc(configuration.getLocalDatacenter())*/.build();

        //TODO: add load balancing support here

        //because client connects to many servers, client can use load balancing
        /*builder.withLoadBalancingPolicy(
                new TokenAwarePolicy(dcAwareRoundRobinPolicy));*/
    }

    Logger.getRootLogger().info("connect to cassandra database.");

    //connect to cluster
    this.cluster = builder.build();

    this.metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
    Logger.getRootLogger().debug("Cassandra Cluster Name: " + this.metadata.getClusterName());

    /**
    * connect to cassandra database
     *
     * @link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_data_model.htm
    */
    this.keyspace = configuration.getDatabase();
    this.session = this.cluster.connect();

    if (!this.keyspace.equals("")) {
        //keyspace support
        try {
            this.session.execute("USE " + this.keyspace);
        } catch (InvalidQueryException e) {
            //create keyspace first
            this.session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE " + this.keyspace + " WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};");

            this.session.execute("USE " + this.keyspace);
        }
    }
```

Why exception is thrown?
What does it means?
Thanks!

EDIT: added code
The method is responsible to connect to cassandra cluster and set keyspace.
Therefor there is an configuration file parsed into Object configuration.

Comment: What is the declaratio of `cluster`? How about `builder`?  Also, please post the COMPLETE stack trace including all "caused by" sections.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do `cluster.connect(...)` before accessing the database?

Comment: @JimGarrison I have added more code above.
This was full stacktrace, there isnt anymore.

Comment: @JimGarrison In many examples, getMetaData() was called before connect(). Do i need to connect first?

EDIT:
I have called connect() before getMetaData() now, but its the same exception.

Comment: @JimGarrison Exception is the same, but now cluster.connect() throws exception.

Comment: Are you sure your configuration points at a valid database on disk? Could the files be corrupted?

Comment: What is the version of cassandra on your cluster and what version of java driver are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am using cassandra driver 3.0.0.

Maven coordinates:
Thanks for your answer! I am using cassandra driver version 3.0.0 . Maven coordinates: <dependency> <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId> <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId> <version>3.0.0</version> </dependency>

On server there is running newest cassandra version 3.4, http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ .

Comment: @JimGarrison And i dont think, that database files are corrupt, because i can access database with for example RazorSQL.

Answer (score 1):

From the line numbers it looks like you're using the driver 3.0.0-alpha2 or earlier. At that time Cassandra was 3.0.0-beta1, and there were a few changes in the metadata format after that.

Try upgrading the driver to 3.0.0, it handles all Cassandra versions properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am using cassandra driver version 3.0.0 .

Maven coordinates:
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Your stacktrace says `ColumnMetadata.java:160`. In 3.0.0, that's not a code line ([link](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.0.0/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ColumnMetadata.java#L160)).

Comment: Thanks!
Very interessting! Maybe maven hasnt updatet artifact, i will check this.

Answer (score 0):

Check you Java driver version and your Cassandra version, they should be aligned

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using cassandra driver version 3.0.0 . Maven coordinates: <dependency> <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId> <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId> <version>3.0.0</version> </dependency>
On server there runs the newest cassandra version 3.4 , but there isnt any other driver available for 3.4.

Comment: Isnt client 3.0.0 compatible with cassandra server 3.4?

Comment: Your driver version is fine, it is compatible with Cassandra 3.4